# What is the diff between React.render(<div></div>, document.body) and React.render( (<div></div>), document.body)

Tags: reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React.js, one question I want to ask is as title mentioned:

```
React.render(<div></div>, document.body)

VS

React.render( (<div></div>), document.body)
```

Why both work(by other means, what that parenthesis does)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that JSX desugars into plain function calls. So, the two examples are really:

```javascript
React.render(React.createElement("div"), document.body)

VS

React.render( (React.createElement("div")), document.body)
```

So, there is no difference. It's analogous to asking what the difference is between

```javascript
alert(add(1, 2));

VS

alert( (add(1, 2)) );
```

---

Parenthesis are often used in React when you want to put the JSX you want to return on a new line:

```javascript
// WON'T WORK, returns undefined
return
  <div>
    test
  </div>;

// WILL work
return (
  <div>
    test
  </div>
);
```

However, this is just like any other JavaScript

```javascript
// WON'T WORK, returns undefined
return
  a + b;

// WILL work
return (
  a + b
);
```

So, just like any other JavaScript, it generally makes no difference, unless you need to group things or use them to continue the statement into the next line.

Comment: Thanks, now I know a little more. BTW, do you have any reference to a good JSX tutorial

Comment: @Kuan, you might enjoy playing with this https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html