# [react]the parenthesis in the render function ES6 syntax or react-only syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button style={{background: this.props.color}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above react component code, there is a **parenthesis pair** right after the **return** statement.

Should it be used when the a function only needs to return a plain JS object? and is it from **es6** syntax or from **reactjs** syntax? thank you!

return **()**

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33166846/1048572) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32772189/1048572) should have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are used to group multiple lines of code to prevent compiler errors from inserting semi-colons erroneously. `return <div></div>` would work fine.

Comment: Got it , much appreciated!

Answer (score -3):

This is not React Syntax, you can do like-

```
render() {
    return 
      <button style={{background: this.props.color}}>
          {this.props.children}
      </button>  
}
```

This will also works fine but as such as complex return wrap in parenthesis would be easy to understand.

Comment: Understand , I didn't see this kind usage until developing in JSX recently , thanks so much!

Comment: This is not correct. Omitting the parenthesis in this case will make the code execute differently and not return the button.